# WordPress useEntityProp returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I have created a custom block use the blocks API.  I am using `useEntityProp` to get/set post meta.  This works fine on my dev server but on the live server `useEntityProp` is returning undefined.

Here is my edit file (console.log(meta) returns undefined) :

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { MediaUpload, useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { useEntityProp } from "@wordpress/core-data";
import { Button } from "@wordpress/components";

const Edit = (props) => {
  let {
    attributes: { foundFeatures, features, gallery, itinerary, duration },
    setAttributes,
    context: { postType, postId },
  } = props;

  let [meta, updateMeta] = useEntityProp("postType", postType, "meta", postId);
```

The context is returning the correct post type and post id.

And I am registering the post meta enabling the `show_in_rest` option

```
    register_post_meta(
        'tour-collection',
        'locations',
        array(
            'show_in_rest'       => true,
            'single'             => true,
            'type'               => 'string',
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add custom-fields to the supports argument when creating the post type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but everything was working ok on my local env just remote won't work so Adding "custom-fields" to the support args did not fix my issue, I had to navigate to Settings -> Permalinks -> and select "Post name" and "save changes" for everything to work as my local env.

I think the permalink structure had to be refreshed for everything to work.